# Can't add the Mobile Apps Tracking bindings to my project

Tags: libgdx, robovm, mobile-app-tracker

I'm trying to use the MAT bindings in my project however it seems that the .jar file is not included on: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/robovm-ios-bindings/

I have also tried adding it to my project by downloading the repository from: https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/mobileapptracking and adding the project to my Robovm build path but it's not working as well.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks,
ASM

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bindings project into a jar file doing the following. I am sure there is an easier way to get the framework in the correct folder, but I have not yet found it.

1. load bindings project in eclipse
2. export the source folder (you should get org/robovm/bindings/mobileapptracking/) to .jar file
3. open the jar file with winrar or similar program
4. add folder: robovm/ios/libs/ in META-INF folder
5. add the .framework(s) to this folder

now you should have a similar .jar file as on the libgdx site!

Comment: Thank you but it still not working for me.
Did you managed to create a working .jar file for the Mobile Apps Tracking bindings ?

Comment: no, I made them for 3 other bindings projects using this method though.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What error do you get? which step didn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I followed your steps I did managed to create a .jar file however it was not good and I couldn't use it.